# Luna Macintosh Eclipse, failing

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Uh, so I had to re-install Eclipse on my Macintosh computer.  I tried the Android SDK version, but it seemed to give me the ancient Juno version when I tried downloading it just now.  Is there a fail at their servers?  I tried also downloading 4.4 (non-Android version) Luna and it also says Juno and doesn't really work.  Anybody else have this same problem? Or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently installed Eclipse on my Mac and I too realized that the SDK bundle from the Android dev site does not use the latest Eclipse.

Here's what I did:

- Install Java JDK 1.7 for Mac from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
- Install Eclipse Luna 64-bit from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/R/eclipse-standard-luna-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz)

And then manually install the Android ADT plugin, and the Android SDK. I put the Android SDK folder in my Applications folder and then have the ADT plugin point to it. But that's my personal preference.

Now, one thing I encountered last week was that the latest ADT/SDK bundle broke some things because of the L Preview. You can probably try downloading the latest SDK now and see if that works, but if you are having trouble, you can do what I did which is to install version 22.6.3 of the ADT and SDK in order to get a stable working environment.

I have Eclipse 4.4 Luna 64-bit using version 22.6.3 of the ADT/SDK on my computer :)

See this post for more help:
[How to install Android ADT/SDK 22.6.3 to avoid L Preview bugs/SDK problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469254/new-android-project-not-creating-layout-or-java-file)

Comment: thanks.  the android SDK for Eclipse seems broken in the current download.  the luna version works, though i had to upgrade my JDK first