# Can't download the older SDK and API from Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I downloaded the latest Eclipse and ADT Bundle from the Android site (adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624) for my Mac (10.8.5). I opened Eclipse and it has installed by default
Android SDK Tools Rev 23, 
Android SDK Platform-tools Rev 20
Android SDK Build-tools Rev 20.

I tried to download all of the older SDK tools and APIs but I encountered the error Runtime Stub!  I tried deleting and redownloading the package but it doesn't fix the issue.  I also don't see any other Stackoverflow threads on this error.

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
Found SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4
Found SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2
Found SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2
Found SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3
Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3
Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2
Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2
Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
Found Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
Found Samples for SDK API 19, revision 5
Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 19.0.2
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
Found Android SDK Tools, revision 22.6.4
Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
Found Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
Found Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
Found Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
Found Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
Found Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3
Found Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3
Found Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 3
Found Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 5
Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
Found Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1
Found Android Support Library, revision 19
Found Android Support Repository, revision 5
Found Google Repository, revision 8
Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
Found Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12
Found Google Play services, revision 17
Found Google USB Driver, revision 10
Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)
Found Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)
Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3 (Obsolete)
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Found Android Support Library, revision 19.1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Found Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 7
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 4
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Found MIPS System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
Found MIPS System Image, Android API 16, revision 4
Found MIPS System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10, revision 2
Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16, revision 1
Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 1
Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Found Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 5
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 1
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Stub!
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml/addon.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml/addon.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/android-wear-sys-img.xml, reason: Runtime Stub!
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 19, revision 5
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 5
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play services, revision 17
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Repository, revision 8
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Web Driver, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 19, revision 5
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 18, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 5
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play services, revision 17
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Repository, revision 8
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Downloading Google Web Driver, revision 2
Download interrupted: Stub!
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs (ARM System Image), Android API 19, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

older [ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)

note you can substitute for other vals like "22.6.3"

[older SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23) see links in accepted answer

download them.

remove the unwanted ADT from eclipse.

Install SDK

Install ADT tarball as 'local repo or archive' install in eclipse "install new software"

Answer (score 1):

You must check **Sdk Manager** permission.

1. SDK Manager -> Right Click
2. Run Admistrator

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469254/new-android-project-not-creating-layout-or-java-file) I wrote last weekend about my problems with the latest ADT/SDK, and how I managed to install Eclipse 4.4 on my Mac and download an earlier version of the ADT/SDK.

It may help you troubleshoot your problems and also get past this blocker :)